# How to pass multiple parameters into SBT in command line?

Tags: scala, functional-programming, sbt

I am learning [scala course](https://class.coursera.org/progfun-005/assignment/view?assignment_id=2) on coursera.

The assignment can be submit like this:

```
 $ sbt shell
 > submit myemail mypassword
```

This works well. However, I was wondering whether I can submit in Bash directly instead of in `sbt shell`, I tried like this:

```
$ sbt submit myemail mypassword
```

And this

```
$ sbt submit "myemail mypassword"
```

But neither works.. Does anyone have ideas about this? Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

After reading the [manual](http://www.scala-sbt.org/0.12.4/docs/Getting-Started/Running.html#batch-mode), I found

```
$ sbt "submit myemail mypassword"
```

works well...